# Order by COUNT in JPQL

Tags: hibernate, jpa, count, group-by, jpql

I have `News` entity in one-to-many relation with `Comments`.
My goal is to sort `News` according to number of comments.
The following query works, but it obviously returns only IDs, not all `News`' fields:

```
SELECT news.id 
    FROM News news JOIN news.comments comments
    GROUP BY news 
    ORDER BY COUNT(comments) DESC
```

If i replace `news.id` with `news`, an error appears:

```
SqlExceptionHelper:146 - ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
```

How to get the entire sorted `News` entities in a single query, not only the IDs?

(Database: Oracle XE, persistence provider: Hibernate)

Comment: Try to use this : SELECT news FROM News news order by size(news.comments)

Comment: Actually it works but too slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the @thanhnguyen [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20117110/jpa-group-by-entity-is-this-possible#20127110):

> If you pass an entity inside the GROUP BY, Hibernate automatically adds its id to the transformed SQL of the underlying DB. In addition, the values in the GROUP BY must exist in the SELECT clause. Thus, instead of select the whole object, you can select its id, then from those ids, you can retrieve the object again.

This could suggest that what you want to do is not possible.

Comment: You gave me a thought:
I added all News fileds to GROUP BY, and know it works.